# I need to remove all values below a certain amount

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to remove all of the values in `CallAmt` below `$51`.

I get an error message `8114` when I run the below query.

I think I need to somehow convert `CallAmt (varchar)` to a decimal and remove the '`$`'.

Any Ideas?

```
Select AccountName, AccountNumber, CallType, CallAmt, TradeDate, DueDate,
CASE
    WHEN CallType = 'RM' THEN 'H'
    WHEN CallType = 'CM' THEN 'H'
    WHEN CallType = 'RT' THEN 'F'
END as CallType

from dbo.EXT250

Where CallType in ('RM', 'CM', 'MD', 'RT') and AccountNumber Not Like '[29]%' and CallAmt > 50.00
```

Comment: If you need to use it as a number, why are you storing it as a varchar in the first place? You can't do math with varchars, you can't properly compare them as numbers (as you can see), and there's no need to store the '$'. Do the pretty formatting stuff in the front end, and use the proper types for storage, and you don't have these issues.

Comment: Understood, however I am pulling the data from a file that has already stored this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
Select AccountName, AccountNumber, CallType, CallAmt, TradeDate, DueDate,
       (CASE WHEN CallType = 'RM' THEN 'H'
             WHEN CallType = 'CM' THEN 'H'
             WHEN CallType = 'RT' THEN 'F'
        END) as CallType
from dbo.EXT250
Where CallType in ('RM', 'CM', 'MD', 'RT') and
      AccountNumber Not Like '[29]%' and
      cast(replace(CallAmt, '$', '') as decimal(10, 4)) > 50.00;
```